# how to prove this inequality $\sum\frac{x}{(n-1)y+1}+\frac{1}{\sum x}\ge\frac{n+1}{n}$

Tags: inequality, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

if $x_{i}>0$,show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{x_{i}}{(n-1)x_{i+1}+1}+\dfrac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}\ge\dfrac{n+1}{n}$$

I have  proven $n=2$and $n=3$

$n=3$ case
let $x,y,z>0$.prove
$$\dfrac{x}{2y+1}+\dfrac{y}{2z+1}+\dfrac{z}{2x+1}+\dfrac{1}{x+y+z}\ge\dfrac{4}{3}$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have 
$$\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{x}{2y+1}\ge \dfrac{(x+y+z)^2}{2xy+2yz+2zx+x+y+z}\ge\dfrac{t^2}{\dfrac{2}{3}t^2+t}=\dfrac{3t}{2t+3}$$
where $t=x+y+z>0$
so we must prove
$$\dfrac{3t}{2t+3}+\dfrac{1}{t}\ge\dfrac{4}{3}$$
the last inequality it is clear true!

Comment: For $n=4$ it's also true and nice.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg,Thanks,How to prove $n=4$ and for $n$ it's right?

Comment: The approach for $n=3$  works for $n=4$ as well, because of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2009517/42969.

Answer (score 1):

A proof for $n=4$.

Let $x+y+z+t=4u$.

Thus, by C-S and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{3y+1}+\frac{1}{x+y+z+t}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2}{3xy+x}+\frac{1}{x+y+z+t}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{(x+y+z+t)^2}{3\sum\limits_{cyc}xy+x+y+z+t}+\frac{1}{x+y+z+t}=\frac{16u^2}{3(x+z)(y+t)+4u}+\frac{1}{4u}\geq$$
$$\geq \frac{16u^2}{3\left(\frac{x+z+y+t}{2}\right)^2+4u}+\frac{1}{4u}=\frac{4u}{3u+1}+\frac{1}{4u}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{4u}{3u+1}+\frac{1}{4u}\geq\frac{5}{4}$$ or
$$(u-1)^2\geq0$$ and we are done.

For $n\geq5$ this way does not help.

Comment: Nice!+1  so  $n\ge 5$  is ugly?

Comment: @inequality Even for $n=5$ after using C-S we obtain a wrong inequality.